# How to create the infobox like it is in a wikipedia page using html?

Tags: html, css

i want to create a box like that is on a wikipedia page about any subject on the right side which has summary about the topic. Two create two columns of information i am using table but the problem is whenever i add two lines of information in the 2nd column the first 1 goes up and doesnt stay inline witht the first row. How to remedy this ? My code is

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Nickname(s)</th>
    <td>
      <span><i>Los Blancos</i> (The Whites)</span><br><span>Los Merengues(The Meringues)</span>
    </td>
  <tr>
    <th>Nickname(s)</th>
    <td>
      <span><i>Los Blancos</i> (The Whites)</span><br><span>Los Merengues(The Meringues)</span>
    </td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have forgotten to close the table row (`<tr>`) tags. Does this solve your problem?

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Nickname(s)</th>
    <td>
      <span><i>Los Blancos</i> (The Whites)</span><br>
      <span>Los Merengues(The Meringues)</span>
    </td>
  </tr> <!-- here -->
  <tr>
    <th>Nickname(s)</th>
    <td>
      <span><i>Los Blancos</i> (The Whites)</span><br>
      <span>Los Merengues(The Meringues)</span>
    </td>
  </tr> <!-- and here -->
</table>
```